# Cannot add new app in iTunes Connect (pop-up menu error)!

Tags: popup, app-store-connect

When in iTunes Connect > My Apps, I click on the "+" sign and the pop-up menu doesn't show, so it is impossible to add a new app.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

This is very stupid as Apple doesn't pop up a warning or something, but there's an updated license agreement on the main page when you log in. You need to click on it, and agree with it after reading it, and once that's confirmed, going back to add app section, you can click on the button, and it'll show you the menu.